# Lilypond-book with Xelatex fails to detect textwidth

Tags: xetex, margins, lilypond

I apologize if this sounds similar to other questions. Apparently I cannot find a solution in other posts, maybe some packages I use are conflicting (fontspec?).

Even running lilypond-book with the correct option (--latex-program=xelatex) xelatex creates an output where music lines are not correctly broken at the textmargins but they are broken at the pagemargins. This causes the music overlappgin the sidepar notes.

Thank you for any suggestion:

```
\documentclass[a3paper, 14pt, twoside, showtrims]{memoir}
\settrimmedsize{340mm}{210mm}{*}
\setlrmarginsandblock{23.3mm}{46.7mm}{*}
\setulmarginsandblock{23.3mm}{54.9mm}{*}
\setmarginnotes{2.8mm}{23.3mm}{1em}
\renewcommand{\sideparfont}{\normalfont\itshape\fontsize{12pt}{12pt}\selectfont‌​\small}
\renewcommand{\footnotesize}{\normalfont\fontsize{12pt}{12pt}\selectfont‌​\small}
\sideparmargin{outer}
\checkandfixthelayout 
\settypeoutlayoutunit{mm}
\typeoutlayout

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text,Style=TitlingCaps,Ligatures={Common}]{Garamond Premier Pro} %\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=Historic} 
\newfontfamily\greekfont[Script=Greek, Ligatures={Common}]{Garamond Premier Pro}
\newfontfamily\devanagarifont[Script=Devanagari]{Sanskrit 2003}


\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{italian}
\setotherlanguage[variant=british]{english}
\setotherlanguage[variant=polytonic]{greek}
\setotherlanguage{sanskrit}

\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}

Even running lilypond-book with the correct option (--latex-program=xelatex) xelatex creates an output where music lines are not correctly broken.\sidepar{\lipsum}

Apparently lilypond-book fails to detect textwidth from LaTex. 

\noindent \begin{lilypond}[fragment,quote,staffsize=12]
\clef bass a,1 b c a b c a b c a b c a b  a b c a b c a b c a b c
\end{lilypond}

\lipsum 

\end{document}
```

Comment: I found that when turning off both fontspec and polyglossia everything works. It's a pity because there's no way to work both with lilypond and xelatex this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, maybe it sounds like a very silly solution, but apparently it works.

I run lilypond-book with lualatex as latex-program. Then I xelatex the resulting texfile. Apparently what xelatex fails to detect is detected by lualatex.

Any comments would be appreciated.

A

Answer (score 3):

Long ago (maybe two years) I had the same problem and lived with a workaround  by setting the line-width option explicitly. Sadly macros are not interpreted by lilypond-book so `line-width=\linewidth` did not work as expected.

Now I found out that loading polyglossia and fontspec inside a `\ifxetex` block restored the functionality of the heuristic line width detection algorithm.

A minimal working example could be:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{ifxetex}
\ifxetex
  %xetex specific stuff
  \usepackage{fontspec,polyglossia}
\fi

\setmainlanguage{english}

\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\title{A short document with LilyPond and XeLaTex}
\maketitle

Normal \textbf{font} commands inside the \emph{text} work,
because they \textsf{are supported by \LaTeX{} and XeteX.}

In normal text you can easily use LilyPond commands, like this:

\begin{lilypond}
    {a2 b c'8 c' c' c'}
\end{lilypond}

\noindent
and so on.

The fonts of snippets set with LilyPond will have to be set from inside of
the snippet. For this you should read the AU on how to use lilypond-book.

\begin{lilypond}
  \score {<<
    \new Staff <<
      \relative c' {
        c4 d e f 
        g a b c
        d e f g 
        a b c2 
        c4 b a g
        f e d c
        b a g f 
        e d c2 \bar "|."
    }
    >>
  >>}
\end{lilypond}

\end{document}
```

Hope this helps anyone.

Comment: That is a very cool fix. When I went to customize the font for the song text I realized I need fontspec for lilypond-book as well. And I found, that add the option `--latex-program=xelatex` to the lilypond-book command did the trick as well. (No need for ifxetex in this case.)